# haml rails forms - html appearing raw instead of rendering as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm using haml 3.1.4 and haml-rails 0.3.5

The issue I'm having only occurs on the server (production) and locally (test) but not in development (both appear to be using the same gem versions)

```
=form_for @thing, :remote => true do |f|
  =hidden_field_tag :template, 'thing'
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th
          Name
        %th
          =image_tag 'cancel.png'
    %tbody
      =f.fields_for :items do |item_fields|
        %tr
          %td
            =f.text_field :name
          %td
  =f.submit 'Save'
```

it outputs the following html save text:

```
<input type='hidden' value='thing' /><table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th><img src='cancel.png.....' /></tr></thead>
```

followed be the rendered html above.

How can I narrow down what the differences are between test/production and development?

Any ideas? :)

EDIT:
It might be worth mentioning that this is the second form for '@thing' on the page.  The first one renders fine, the second one is where the issue is.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to have the "=" on the form_for line.  Try "- form_for".  I've been tripped up by this before, though it's weird you're seeing different behavior in development.

Comment: You need the `=` because that's what outputs the form HTML tags.

Comment: so the rendered output after the closing `</thead>` is all escaped like `&lt;tbody&gt;`? Also, did you miss the closing `</th>` or is this part of the problem?

Comment: I checked production Gem.loaded_specs for the haml version and they are the same as development.  I was really hoping that was the issue.

Comment: Haml should be generating the closing th

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple theories.

Whitespace is very important in haml. Is it possible you have a tab somewhere and whitespaces elsewhere?

Do both your `form_for`s have `remote: true`? That creates some extra div output which I suppose could confuse the DOM if it's reusing ids.

Are you sure you are using the `=` on `form_for` because without it, it won't output the HTML form tags.

I'm afraid I'm just guessing, and none of these would explain why it works in development.

Perhaps it helps...

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are not closing the  tag is this your problem? Anyway in regards to narrowing down the differences between test/prod/dev you really need to check out the contents of your `/config/` folder. I can suggest for testing that you can use the `Rails.env == "development"` for choosing your environment and then trying the **debugger** and looking for differences.

Comment: haml doesn't require closing tags.

Comment: well the html output doesn't show a closing tag so I took it just like the `%td
            =f.text_field :name
          %td` the `%table` might need one also just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using two different versions of haml. Could be one version is more strict on the space after the '='. I would write it like:

```
= form_for @thing, :remote => true do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :template, 'thing'
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Name
        %th= image_tag 'cancel.png'
    %tbody
      = f.fields_for :items do |item_fields|
        %tr
          %td= f.text_field :name
          %td
  = f.submit 'Save'
```